# testng.xml to execute all tests, including the ones that may be added in the future

Tags: testng

What's the proper content for the testng.xml file so that I can capture all tests, without having to worry about changing it in the future?

I already tried

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Unit Tests" verbose="1" >
    <test name="sample-Test" >
        <packages>
            <package name=".*"/>
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

but no tests are ran.

Adding classes by name will ensure that tests are ran, but then this requires changes in the future, which is what I'm trying to avoid in the first place.

This is testng-6.10, and according to [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html) docs, just having packages document fragment should be enough to run all tests.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Lets say all your packages begin with `com.` so perhaps you could use something like below

```
<packages>
    <package name="com.*"/>
</packages>
```

Wouldn't that help ?

Comment: That will only work so far: some tests are in the no name package. Also, it's possible that some tests will be added in a different package (eg org.).

The end goal would be to drive everything trough groups, hence the "include everything" goal.